# installing .net framework 4.6 error

Tags: windows-8.1

i need help. This microsoft is so stupid. I downloaded the Windows8.1-KB2919355-x86 then it says it is not for my pc. Then how can i install .net framework when it always says i need to install KB291935. I am in Windows x86 8.1 Pro. Please help.. I dont know what to do with this..

Error installing the .net 4.6
[image: Here is the error with installing .net 4.6]

[image: Error installing the KB]

Comment: try to install 4.6.2: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53344

Comment: provide an answer sir. its already okay

Comment: done, I created an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing the older .net 4.6 version, you should install the [.net framework 4.6.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/) with a lof of fixes and improvements. Get it [here from the downloadcenter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53344)

Answer (score 0):

KB2919442 is a prerequisite for Windows 8.1 update and should be installed before attempting to install KB2919355.